# Processing + Arduino + Serial port + Cp5.listbox

Tags: user-interface, listbox, serial-port, arduino, processing

I would like to create a "listbox" (using the controlP5 GUI library) containing the serial port list: the goal is to create a stand alone app using Processing to communicate with Arduino Uno, independently from which OS I'm going to use (win, mac or linux), and select (with the "listbox") the correct Serial Port to communicate with Arduino. 
is it possible??

Answer (score 2):

```
ControlP5 cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
ListBox listBox = cp5.addListBox("serialPorts");
Serial serial;
String[] ports = Serial.list();
for (int i=0; i<ports.length; i++) {
    listBox.addItem(ports[i]);
}

void controlEvent(ControlEvent theEvent) {
    if(theEvent.isGroup() && theEvent.name().equals("myList")){
        int val = (int)theEvent.group().value();
        serial = new Serial(this, ports[val], 9600);
    }
}
```

untested, but that's the basic idea...